# What is the difference between clearing a cookie and deleting a cookie?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In the **Cookies** category of the **Resources** panel there are three buttons at the bottom: refresh, clear, and delete. What is the difference between clearing a cookie and deleting a cookie?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Clear** clear all the cookies.
**Delete** delete the selected cookie.